# How to prove that multiplication distributes over addition in a certain number system H

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Numbers in $H$ are ordered pairs of integers, i.e. $(a,b) \in \mathbb{H}$ if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, with addition and multiplication defined by

$$(a,b)+(c,d) := (a+c,b+d),\\
(a,b)*(c,d) := (ac-5bd , ad+bc).$$

I'm kind of stuck where to start to prove that multiplication distributes over addition

(I tried using mathjax but it's not working? Sorry I'm new to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any three elements of $H$, $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ and $(e,f)$

What you must prove is that $$(a,b)*((c,d) + (e,f)) = ((a,b) * (c,d)) + ((a,b)*(e,f)).$$

I suggest you try to rewrite both sides of the equation, so you first rewrite $$(a,b)*((c,d) + (e,f))$$
to $$(a,b)*(c+e,d+f)$$
and so on.